# Observable is empty Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would check that Observable has no element 
I do something like this

```
unusedElements$: Observable<Array<string>> = this.elements;

isEmpty(): boolean {
  let empty = false;
  this.unusedElements$.subscribe(res => res.length > 0 ? empty = !empty : empty).unsubscribe();
  return empty;
}
```

I wonder this is the right way? Is maybe possible checking without subscribing if Observable has no element in Array?

Comment: Empty Observable is an Observable that only emits `complete` notification and no `next` notifications. So the only way to tell whether an Observable is empty is by waiting until it completes.

Comment: By the look of the code if unusedElements is not an aysnc operation but  a data store there's no need for converting it to observable.

Comment: @martin I asked the wrong question, it is more about situations where the subscription has an empty array of elements and if it is a bad solution, is it better to check if the Observable isEmpty

Comment: @FanCheung I simplified the code. Variable elements is type observable

Answer (score 2):

if you program in an functional fashion, there are very few situations you will have to use something like isSomething() to return boolean value, unless it is useful for other stream to reuse.

Most of the time you can just use filter to silent the emission. In case you still want to subscribe to different case you can split stream like below and continue you work. There also a `partition` operator you can use

```
const hasItem=unusedElements$.pipe(filter(res=>res.length>0))
hasItem.pipe(....do something)

const noItem=unusedElements$.pipe(filter(res=>res.length===0))
noItem.pipe(....do something)
```

functional programming is about break up your tasks and recompose them for business requirement